# how to limit aws eks error and help page output in shell and show only N first lines? head not working

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, eksctl

i m trying diff commands in aws eks and when there is wrong cmd it spits out too long of output.

```
aws kubectl get pod

usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters
]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help

aws: error: argument command: Invalid choice, valid choices are:

accessanalyzer                           | account

acm                                      | acm-pca

alexaforbusiness                         | amp

amplify                                  | amplifybackend
```

in case i only want to see the error msg and not 2 screens of all possible cmds how to limit the output in case of error?

i tried :

```
aws eks describe-cluster --voice wrongparameter | head 10
```

but it s not working

Answer (score 1):

There is no such command `aws kubectl get pod` !!

It is either `kubectl get pod` to list pods in current namespace if you have [kubectl](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/#kubectl) cli installed and configured with the correct context or `aws eks describe-cluster --name demo` to describe your AWS Kubernetes cluster with name `demo` in the current region and profile.

Comment: ok, but official docs dont show any aws eks get pod command. there used to be eksctl tool, but no longer there. so it means if i want to get pods - i need to set up my local kubectl cli to get pods in aws eks cluster?

Comment: If you want to list pods you need many steps before that

1- AWS EKS cluster uo and running.

2- AWS CLI and Kubectl tools installed in your local machine.

3- run `aws eks update-kubeconfig --region <region> --name <cluster_name>   --alias <alias>` to add context to your local config.

4- check if all ok by running `kubectl get pod`.

Comment: i did all these steps and it worked. i could even create pod via kubectl. i was wondering where is eksctl tool

Comment: [eksctl](https://eksctl.io/) is now open source project and is a simple CLI tool for creating and managing clusters on EKS, not for managing Kubernetes resources such as pods

Comment: omg, and i was thinking its same. so the only way to manage k8s resources is just to connect my kubectl to existing cluster?

Comment: yes  exactly   `kubectl` is  for managing Kubernetes resources